# Callback For Tasks

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a tasks using the following code

```
For (//pls ignore the variables)
            Dim task = (New System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory()).StartNew(
            Sub()
                downloadFiles()
            End Sub
            )

Next
```

The task is created n number of times and it works fine asynchronously. Now I don't know how to add a callback method for this . Can anyone please tell me how to add callback for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Use of Callback should look like this:
I left out the for...each.

```
 Private Sub StartTask_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles StartTask.Click
    Dim LongTask As Task = (New System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory).StartNew(AddressOf DoWorkAsync)
    LongTask.ContinueWith(AddressOf WorkCompleted)
    Debug.Print("")
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Called after DoWorkAsync Task is complete
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <remarks></remarks>
  Private Sub WorkCompleted()
    Debug.Print("completed")
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Called by Task
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <remarks></remarks>
  Public Sub DoWorkAsync()
    For i = 0 To 2000
      Debug.Print("test")
    Next
  End Sub
```